# Convert :hover menu to onclick for use on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a drop down menu using css and am now trying to convert this for use on mobile by changing the hover function to onclick.

I've seen a couple of other examples on here of how this could be achieved but my javascript knowledge is pretty limited, so I've had trouble trying to implement the suggestions.

This is the css code that I'm using make the menu items appear.

```
#submenu-1 li:hover>ul {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
max-height: 700px;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Please show your effort. Your question should be more specific. Also show your menu markup.

Comment: There's nothing to do, it should works fine like this

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to let css handle the :hover event, then use a media query to check for acreen size and turn off the hover accordingly.  Once that is done, write the js for the section to change the innerHTML to match what you want.

If you want to you can write two different menus and use the display:none attribute in css to hide the mobile menu.  That way you can have the menus you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "touchstart" event like this

```
$('#submenu-1 li').on('touchstart',function(){
    $('ul',this).css({
         "visibility": "visible",
         "max-height": "700px"
    });
    $('ul',this).animate({opacity:1},5000);
});
```

Comment: Good answer, but would the `tap` event not be even better? That way if the user is scrolling, etc then the menu won't be opened as `tap` only applies for a short touch event on a single element.

Comment: I saw your other comment so I checked because I never used tap to be honnest. But it appears it's less supported crossbrowsers (you can doublecheck to prove me wrong I did it quickly)

Comment: Fair, don't want it only working on some browsers! I haven't used tap either, was just flicking through the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can check mobile by using
`screen.width`
check if it is less than 450px if yes then
`$('#submenu-1 li').attr('onClick','yourfunction()')`